# Basic rails creating model with multiple has_one relations question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've got HostPublicEvent class and Band class.   I need a BandSlot class that shows the start time of the Band in the HostPublicEvent (the hour and minute that the Band starts playing during the HostPublicEvent).

In the new BandSlot model, this is probably what needs to be:

- has_one :band
- has_one :host_public_event

And in the Band model:

- has_many: band_slots

And in the HostPublicEvent model:

- has_many: band_slots

I'm thinking this might set up the model with the references, and then I go into each model and adjust them accordingly?   This is my first coding project, thanks!

```
    rails generate model BandSlot start_time_hour:integer start_time_minute:integer host_public_event:references band:references
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up `has_one` and `belongs_to`. Which is a really common newbie misstake.

`belongs_to` goes on the side with the foreign key column. `has_one` points to the foreign key column on *the other model*.

The inverse of a `has_many` association is always `belongs_to`. If you use `has_one` instead you just get a circular reference where both models expect the foreign key to be on the other side.

```
class BandSlot 
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :host_public_event
end

class Band
  has_many :band_slots
  has_many :host_public_events, through: :band_slots
end

class HostPublicEvent
  has_many :band_slots
  has_many :bands, through: :band_slots
end
```

This example creates a many to many assocation between Band and HostPublicEvent with BandSlot as a join table.

Comment: Sweet, I appreciate that.   ... I'm sure the last line in class HostPublicEvent is meant to read 'has_many :bands, through: :band_slots'.   Next step is to read up on general foreign key info.

Comment: Yeah, copy-pasta got me.